# Why does @emotion/styled not render the styled component on screen?

Tags: css, reactjs, emotion, css-in-js

I am trying to use @emotion/styled. But, I cannot get the components to render on the screen, whereas if I am using the HTML element it is working fine.

```
import styled from "@emotion/styled";
    
export const Button = styled.button`
   color: red;
   background-color: green;
`;
```

```
import { Button } from "../styles/Button";

const Test = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Button>Hello</Button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Test;
```

Does anyone has any idea where things are going wrong?

Comment: Have you installed @emotion/react dependency ?

Comment: Yes I have, still there is some problem and I can't figure out what!

Answer (score 0):

It is working in my sandbox here

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/emotion-styled-hb5eri?file=/src/App.js)

```
import "./styles.css";
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

const Button = styled.button`
  color: red;
  background-color: green;
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Button>Hello</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes! It's working in a sandbox for me too, but not in dev machine.

Answer (score 0):

try to import this on top of your component where you use emotion css.
This fixed my problems with not loading emotion css. Cheers!

```
/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `styled` with `css` function to make a new component by updating some styles of existing component.

```
import styled from "@emotion/styled";
import { css } from "@emotion/react";
import { Button as MUIButton } from "@mui/material";

export const Button = styled(MUIButton)(
  css({
    backgroundColor: "green",
    color: "red",
  })
);
```